# Call action from another action

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have this code;

```
Button button = new Button();
MessageBox ms = new MessageBox(button);

 Action<bool> action = ms.Show();
 action += (b) =>
 {
      Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()); //this isnt working
      Console.WriteLine("??");
 };

Console.Read();
button.OnClick();
Console.ReadKey();
```

MessageBox class :

```
class MessageBox
{
    Button _button;
    public MessageBox(Button button) { _button = button; }//initialize button
    public Action<bool> Show()
    {
        Action<bool> action = new Action<bool>(CallForTest);
        _button.OnClick+=()=>{ action?.Invoke(true); };
        return action;
    }
    //...working.*//
    public void CallForTest(bool statu){} 
}
```

I want to return an action and when button is clicked,call the action.But this isnt working? What is the problem? Action is a delegate so delegate is a reference type?(compiler generated class) What is wrong in this picture?

I think when "Show()" is ends,"action" is collected from gargabe collector.But this is working with other reference types? for example;

```
public Test Show()
{
 Test test = new Test("??");
 button.OnClick += () =>
 {
    test.JustForTest(); //working (cw("?????" + ctorvalue);
 };
   return test;
}
```

Comment: That's good. Keep coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are immutable. When you are combining two delegates using `+=`, you are actually creating a new delegate. So when you have done `act += ...` in the above code, you have actually created a new delegate, it is different from what you have already created in `Show()` method.

Comment: I did not know that.Do you mean "action?.Invoke" is just referencing "CallForTest" method when I call "_button.OnClick" because delegates are immutable? So in _button.OnClick,action is referencing old action in memory right?

Comment: Right. Delegates are immutable; once created, the invocation list of a delegate does not change. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because when you use `+=` to a delegate it does not append to the internal list. This is why you don't see `b.string()` being printed

Without changing your design you won't be able to append the action to the original delegate when the button is clicked.

What you are actually writing is somthing like:

```
var act2 = new Action<bool>((b) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()); //this isnt working
            Console.WriteLine("??");
        });

var act = act + act2;
```

as you can see act is getting a new reference to the combined expression of `act + act2` rather than `act` itself concatenating `act2` internally.

if you do `act(false)` you will see the extra results, but not if you invoke the button click.

What you should be using is `event` on the delegate within the Button, which is the way UI controls are written

```
class Button
{
     public event EventHandler<BoolEventArgs> Click;
}
```

best to read up on using events when you want to have multicast delegates in this way. [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)